# How well do multi objective optimization algorithms such NSGAii scale when there are many objectives (for example 10 or more)?

Tags: algorithms, optimization

What I'm trying to figure out is what happens when using a multi objective optimization algorithm such as NSGA-ii and instead of trying to find the usual 2/3 objectives, I use 10 or many more objectives?

Comment: Have you given it a try? Also, what do you mean precisely with "what happens"?

Comment: @Juho Apologies, I shouldve been more specific. Im wondering basically whether it will still be able to find the entire set of pareto optimal solutions (within the range of values that I have chosen for the input variables of course)? I have tried it however only using a small range of values for the input variables. Im not sure whether what I receive as the output is correct and I dont know how to test to check that it is right.

Comment: Please edit all this information into the question itself. But do note that in the title you ask about scalability, whereas in the comment you seem to be asking about correctness.